Handling whether properties are optional or not optional based on generic parameter
I'm trying to infer the right data types from a Zod schema collection from within a function.
For this I defined two types for inferring a resulting plain JS object of Zod parsed types.  That is, ValidationSchema constitutes a base type and SafeData the type for inference based on a generic parameter. I though that as SafeData 's props are mapped to ValidationSchema's which are optional ? then SafeData 's should too.
Also defined a simple testing function receiving a parameter of SafeData type  that inserts into a database values received in its body property. But upon finishing writing the database operation's code I get that .body should be an Object type not Object | undefined .  Well, this had to be expected, but I find cumbersome to have to cast with the as keyword or using Exclude  type from within any function to get rid of the undefined.
Clarification: While I added zod library to the example, I'm not searching for a solution with zod, it's only typescript based. I think it should be easily possible to express as I said below in the comments that : "if an obj.property is an optional string according to the contract but its actual instance is a string then it should be a string and not string | undefined". This way type inference is delegated to types and no need to add casting or typeguards within the callee.
The objective: to have either SafeData  or a helper type(s) determine "optionalitiness" of SafeData properties based on its passed generic parameter.
export type ValidationSchema = {
    bodySchema?: ZodTypeAny;
    pathParamSchema?: ZodTypeAny;
    queryParamSchema?: ZodTypeAny;
}


export type SafeData<S extends ValidationSchema = ValidationSchema> = {
    body?:
        S["bodySchema"] extends infer Type
            ? Type extends ZodTypeAny
            ? z.infer<Type>
            : never
            : never

    pathParams?:
        S extends { pathParams: ZodTypeAny }
            ? S extends { pathParams: ZodTypeAny }
            ? z.infer<S["pathParams"]>
            : undefined
            : never

    queryParams?:
        S["queryParamSchema"] extends infer Type
            ? Type extends ZodTypeAny
            ? z.infer<Type>
            : undefined
            : never
}

Testing function:
async function insertRestaurant(safeData: SafeData) {
    await db.insert(restaurant).values(safeData.body) // Error! because db.insert(table).values() expects an actual object, not object | undefined.
}

I also wrote an alternative version to solve it. Still doesn't work, nor do I know whether I am on the right track:
export type ValidationSchema = {
    bodySchema?: ZodTypeAny;
    pathParamSchema?: ZodTypeAny;
    queryParamSchema?: ZodTypeAny;
}

type OptionalKeys<T> = { [K in keyof T]-?: undefined extends T[K] ? K : never }[keyof T];
type RequiredKeys<T> = { [K in keyof T]-?: undefined extends T[K] ? never : K }[keyof T];


export type SafeData<S extends ValidationSchema = ValidationSchema> = {
    [K in keyof S as K extends 'bodySchema' ? 'body' : K extends 'pathParams' ? 'pathParams' : K extends 'queryParamSchema' ? 'queryParams' : never]?:
        K extends 'bodySchema'
            ? z.infer<S[K]>
            : K extends 'pathParams'
                ? z.infer<S[K]>
                : z.infer<S[K]>;
} & {
    [K in RequiredKeys<S>]: z.infer<S[K]>;
};


I guess the simplest solution would be to just make the properties of ValidationSchema required - you can still default them to zod.never() schemas if you want

Or also consider making ValidationSchema an actual zod.object schema, not an object containing three schemas. Then export type SafeData<S extends z.ZodType<{body: any, pathParams: any, queryParams: any}>> = z.infer<S>

It surely is a workaround to this specific case. But, title-wise, I think this is a common problem and it would be very helpfully intuitive and concise to express that "if an obj.property is an optional string according to the contract but its actual instance is a string then it should be a string and not string | undefined.

I'd like to add that, in further steps in my python-to-node/typescript migration I'll be facing the same pattern in contexts where zod is superfluous.

Oh! I forgot there existed this functionality :). @Bergi
